# Apply properties defined in a dependency: spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm building a jar package for others to use, and I want the configuration that I do in my app to take effect in the consumer application.

For example, let's say a project `com.example.demo` has a dependency on my jar package `org.xyz.jar-with-config` and I have some properties defined in the `jar-with-config` and I want those properties to take effect in `com.example.demo`

I tried to configure some slo buckets for micrometer-prometheus-registry for the jar package and needed it to take effect in the application which requires my jar as dependency but that's not happening. There's also a logback.xml file in the module which I want to be read if no logback.xml is provided in the dependent project.

`application.yml`

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /management
      exposure:
        include: ["env", "metrics", "prometheus", "health", "info"]
  metrics:
    enabled: true
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
    web:
      server:
        auto-time-requests: false
    distribution:
      percentiles:
        all: 0.95, 0.99
      slo:
        http:
          server:
            requests: 50ms, 100ms, 250ms, 500ms, 1s, 3s, 5s
          client:
            requests: 10ms, 25ms, 50ms, 100ms, 250ms, 500ms, 750ms, 1s, 2s
  prometheus:
    enabled: true
```

I want this to be therein my project `com.example.demo` which includes this jar as a dependency.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-auto-configuration